# JPA/hibernate time stamp not getting saved in database/object entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, date, timestamp

I am using javax.persistence for my entity object.Mysql for database
My entity object has a field entryDate

```
@Column(name = "ENTRYDATE")   
private Date entryDate=new Date();
```

and when i save the object using saveOrupdate method only the date gets saved. I also
want to save the time stamp along with date. I do not explicitly set the date since i have
already declared it along with the field declaration above.
How can i get time also to be saved along with date.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Use

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```

on your attribute.

Comment: Exactly. To clarify further, if you are using java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar, you need to specify the temporal-type (TemporalType.Date for only day, month and year, TemporalType.TIME for only time (hours, minutes, seconds) or TemporalType.TIMESTAMP for both time and date). If you are using java.sql.Date, java.sql.Time or java.sql.Timestamp, the @Temporal-annotation is not needed.

Comment: I am using java.util.Date. I have tried @Temporal annotation as well. But still time stamp is saved as 00:00:00 00 . Wonder what am i doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: @Daniel I'm saving two instances of Calendar. I have set the first instance to variable1 and rolled the same date by a week and saved it to variable2. When I save the object in the database, both the attributes have same value which was the value of the first Calendar instance. I don't know what the problem is as when I print them prior to persisting the object, their values are what they should be.

Comment: @nick-s: Please open a new question for this and show parts of your code.

Comment: @Daniel: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277737/rolled-calendar-isnt-persisting-as-desired

Comment: Great answer thank you, I was using the @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) so it was only saving the date bit, I changed it to @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) and it's working fine now. Thank you.

Comment: I am facing same problem..but not working this answer for me. :( any idea?

Comment: why use that annotation at all? I just took it off altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column(name = "ENTRYDATE")  
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) 
private Date entryDate=new Date();
```

Try to use this if you want to save timestamp otherwise you can use TemporalType.Date (for saving only date) and TemporalType.Time (for saving only time)