# Rolled Calendar isn't persisting as desired

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, calendar

I am trying to roll a calendar by a week and persist it using Hibernate. The rolling work (tested using *println*) but the data being saved in the database seems to be the original calendar.

```
    Calendar outDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(outDate.getTime());
    Loan loan = new Loan();
    loan.setCatalogueEntry(catalogueEntry);
    loan.setOutDate(outDate);
    loan.setNoOfRenewals(0);
    outDate.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);  //Rolling the calendar to a week further
    System.out.println(outDate.getTime());
    loan.setDueDate(outDate);
    loan.setUser(user); 

    loanDao.save(loan);
    catalogueEntryDao.update(catalogueEntry);
```

`GenericHibernateDao<T, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, ID>` class has following method:

```
@Override
public void save(T instance) {
    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(instance);
}
```

`public interface LoanDao extends GenericDao<Loan, Long>` doesn't have any implementation of save method.

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: could you post your println()?

Comment: Post your LoadDao and your hibernate.xml

Comment: @Daniel: Please check the update. Also, my sessionfactory is instantiated via a spring bean and not hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the same Calendar instance in dueDate and outDate! When you set the outDate, the Calendar is e.g. the 2012-07-02, and then you update the calendar value to 2012-07-09, and store it in dueDate.

The problem is, the same calendar instance is also used for outDate, so when Hibernate persists your object, it stores it completely right, since both attributes share the same Calendar object.

Clone the calendar before updating it, and your problem is solved.

AND: The date stored in the database is both times the dueDate calendar, not the original calendar as you posted!

Comment: yeah I figured that out, just couldn't find the time to answer it. Since, you have already answered the question in detail saving me a hassle, I just accepted your answer. Thanks for your time though.

Answer (score 0):

roll doesn't change larger fields ([see JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html))

use

```
outDate.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
```

instead

Comment: Useful addition, but probably not related to the actual problem. That the larger fields are not modified only means that the rolled field will go back to its minimum value if the roll operation would mean that the maximum value is exceeded. E.g. if the calendar is set to April 30th and you roll the DAY_OF_MONTH field by 1, the result would be April 1st. Adding one to DAY_OF_MONTH would result in May 1st.

Comment: Mon Apr 29 22:50:48 EST 2013
Mon May 06 22:50:48 EST 2013

These are the outputs. Their values are displayed before persisting.

Comment: you could try debugging whenever the setter is called. maybe it's invoked and you don't want it to

Comment: @PhilippSander I didn't get you

Comment: put a println in the DueDate-Setter. now you can see how often it is invoked.